# React Native library development and usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, library-project

I develop apps in React Native, I need to build my own libraries and reuse them in multiple React Native projects.
With React Native I couldn’t link a library from outside the project, so I can't simply link my library to all my React Native apps.
What is the right way to do that?

I need to have a development environment to develop and test my library, but I need also to import my library into all the projects I need.

Comment: If you don't want to do `npm install` every time you change the lib (you can use local paths in package.json), then symlinks are the only option for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, could you please provide some links? I can't find any guide

Comment: [Npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) for symlinking and local paths in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths).